# If $X$ is a finite dimensional vector space, is it true that $\bigcap_{k=1}^n ker(f_k) =\{0\}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}?$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a vector space.
Assume that $f_1,...,f_n$ are linear functionals (may not be bounded) on $X.$

It can be shown that if 
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^n ker(f_k)=\{0\},$$
then $X$ is finite dimensional.

I would like to know whether the converse holds, that is,

> If $X$ is finite dimensional, is it true that 
>   $$\bigcap_{k=1}^n ker(f_k) =\{0\}$$
>   for any $n\in\mathbb{N}?$

It seems true to me as linear functionals on finite dimensional vector space, say $\mathbb{R}^m,$ have trivial kernel. 
But I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: I am pretty sure you want to avoid examples like $f_k =0$ for all $k=1,2,\cdots$. What kind of functionals do you want to look at?

Comment: @SangchulLee: Maybe exclude zero functional? That is, all linear functionals exclude zero functional.

Comment: There are three possibilities for $\rm{ker ~f}$:

$$1) \{0\} , ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~2) \rm{n-1 ~ dimension ~ subspacce}   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~3) X$$

Comment: @Redshoes: I see. So the converse does not hold for any linear functional, right? Because codimension of kernel of linear functional is always $1.$

Comment: Now that I think about it carefully, it seems that converse fails even in $X = \mathbb{R}^2.$ Take $f_1$ and $f_2$ to be planes passing through origin. Then their intersection may not be trivial.

Comment: right. If you want convers hold, you need to restrict yourself to certain type of functionals.

Comment: Let me be more specific. Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$ and consider $L : X \to F^n$ given by $F = (f_1, \cdots, f_n)$. Then $\ker L = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \ker f_i$ and by the Rank-Nullity theorem, $$ \dim X = \dim \ker L + \dim \operatorname{im} L. $$ Now notice that you have the full control over $\operatorname{im} L$, i.e., for any subspace $W$ of $F^n$ you can find $L$ such that $\operatorname{im} L = W$.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously false as a theorem reads as follows

> If $f_1,\cdots,f_n$ are linear functionals over a linear space $V$, then each linear functional vanishing on $\bigcap_{k=1}^n\ker f_k$ is a linear combination of $f_1,\cdots,f_n$.

The converse also holds apparently and thus numerous counterexamples for your question can be constructed.